# Remove empty classes

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

**Remove empty classes**

how to remove empty classes in wp menu? walker menu

I have the following code:

```js
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'discard_menu_classes', 10, 2);

function discard_menu_classes($classes, $item) {
  $classes = array_filter(
    $classes,
    create_function('$class',
      'return in_array( $class, 
      array("current-menu-item", "current-menu-parent"));
    ' )
  );
  return array_merge(
      $classes,
      (array) get_post_meta($item - > ID, '_menu_item_classes', true)
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-2338" class=""><a href="#">Text</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-2058" class=""><a href="#">Text</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-18781" class=""><a href="#">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

**SOLVED:**

i managed to solve it

following is the code

```js
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'strip_empty_classes');

function strip_empty_classes($menu) {
  $menu = preg_replace('/ class=""/', '', $menu);
  return $menu;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-2338" class=""><a href="#">Text</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-2058" class=""><a href="#">Text</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-18781" class=""><a href="#">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You might want to add php as a tag on this one buddy :)

Comment: What is the driver for this? Is it causing a problem?

Comment: @Phil, wordpress, the walker menu, submenu......, i don't know how quit / hide (without js) the empty classes.......

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question... why do you want to do this? What is the reason?

Comment: @Phil, clean the code, clean dom, no extra code without sense...

Comment: To what benefit? With GZip compression, the repeated `class=""` become practically non-existent

Comment: more clean code, more clear dom..........

Comment: i got it:

''' add_filter ('wp_nav_menu','strip_empty_classes');
function strip_empty_classes($menu) {
    $menu = preg_replace('/ class=""/','',$menu);
    return $menu;
}'''

Comment: @Phil, with http2 too, and varnish, and cache...., That is not the question, the question was how clean and empty useless tags that only dirty and grow the dom........

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer. Also, this is always worth a read ~ https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

```
add_filter ('wp_nav_menu','strip_empty_classes');
function strip_empty_classes($menu) {
    $menu = preg_replace('/ class=""/','',$menu);
    return $menu;
}
```